# Is O(n^n) and O(n!) equivalent?

Tags: big-o

Is `O(n!)` the same as `O(n^n)`? I read that `O(log(n!))` is the same as `O(nlog(n))`. However, I suspect that `O(n!)` is not the same as `O(n^n)` because the limit of n^n/n! as n approaches infinity is infinity by the ratio test, which thereby indicates that `O(n^n)` has a faster rate of growth than `O(n!)`. Is this a correct justification?

Comment: You are correct; they are not equivalent.

Comment: Yes you are currect. the limit of (n^n)/(n!) when n->infinity is infinity. That means o(n^n) is not equal to o(n!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition and reasoning is correct. A proof sketch that would formally show this would be to see if `n^n` is `O(n!)`, which we do easily by using the [limit test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925053/using-limits-to-determine-big-o-big-omega-and-big-theta), in which we find that [`n^n` is **not** `O(n!)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+n+goes+to+infinity+of+(n%5En)%2Fn!), so there there exists a function that is `O(n^n)` but not `O(n!)` and the two sets are not the same thing.